# Wordpress form action redirects to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm working on a site with a searchbar functionality and have the search results template all ready to go.  However, in my header.php I have a form that has the URL of my search template as the action property but when I click the input with type="submit" instead of going to the search results page it redirects to the homepage with the keyword for the search appended to the URL(which is what I want since my search results page gets that parameter from the URL).

I have tried both GET and POST as the method to use with the form.  With GET it appends the keyword to the URL but goes to the homepage. 
With POST it doesn't append my parameters into the URL but it goes to my search results page.

Here is the code I have:

```
<?php 
$searchPage = custom function that gets my template-search.php(search results page) which is a custom post type
$sPID = $searchPage->getPostID();
$searchURL = get_permalink($sPID);
?>

<form action="<?=$searchURL?>" method="GET">
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="wd_keyword" placeholder="Find deals for..."/>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're probably going to need to edit your question and show the search page function...

Comment: How does your $searchURL look like? Is it a something like http://example.com/my-post/ or http://example.com/?p=123 ?

Comment: @AndreasKrischer $searchURL looks like (http://example.com/?wd_miscpageslug=search-results-page")